# Alternative to Eclipse Web Service explorer for Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, netbeans, jboss

Am trying to find an alternative to the Web Service Explorer in eclipse for netbeans.  I really love that feature and was wondering if there is something similar in nebeans.  An explorer that takes a wsdl and give you an explorer window to test your webservice.

Edit:
Please note that am using JBoss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try SOAPUI for this purpose. On top of exploration it can invoke/test and mock services. They also have a free version.

Apparently there is also an eclipse plugin if you want to use it in Eclipse.

http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/eclipse-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly same as Eclispe but serves similar purpose. Just right click on project and select "Test Web Service"

[image]

[image]

More details :  http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/javaee5/screencasts/hello-simple-client-glassfish/

Comment: @rtp: Still you can give a try.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work on Jboss 6... the test webservice is not clickable

Comment: @rtp: Ok. Will check again for any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

May this is the one you need. Expand the project's Web Services node. Right-click the FlowerService and select Test Web Service

[image]

Comment: It doesn't depend with server. you could you any webserver in netbeans. Netbeans installer comes with Tomcat and Glassfish.

Comment: I can confirm that it doesn't work on Jboss 6... the test webservice is not clickable.